# What type of shell is this?(Answered)

Tags: species-identification, marine-biology, invertebrates

This is Calcareus tube worm and Was found and Located on Culebra Island, Puerto Rico

Picture 1: A up close image of the shell

Picture 2: a view of the top part of the shell showing the shells coloring.

Credits for the answer: @Jiminy Cricket

Website Credits:

https://gohiking.ca/animals/fish/marine-worms/calcareous-tube-worm/

[image]

[image]

Comment: given that they are both calcium carbonate, as soon as the coral started growing on it, the fusion process would have started.

Comment: perhaps it's a parchment tube or a keel worm. https://www.beachstuff.uk/marine_worms.html

Comment: Could you try to make some pictures with a scale? It would be helpful to see a bit more of it. To secure it in place you could place it on some plasticine, than you don´t have to hold it and the hand isn´t the star of the picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a [Tube Worm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tube_worm).

[image: Squiggled tubes on a rock]

<sup>Calcareous Tube Worm, Vancouver Island, BC, Photo By Bud Logan
From [Gohiking.ca](https://gohiking.ca/animals/fish/marine-worms/calcareous-tube-worm/).</sup>

They anchor themselves to rocks, or animal shells, poking out their filter-feeding aparatus which draws small invertebrates and algae into the mouth. As they grow they deposit a calcerous tube around their bodies for shelter from abraisive silt-carrying currents
and protection.

They're seen in a variety of sizes and shapes in marine habitats, from squiggles on rocks to large, straight stands, much like a small forest.

Giant Tube Worms: (Courtessy of [Seasky.org](http://www.seasky.org/deep-sea/giant-tube-worm.html))

[image]

<sup>NOAA, public domain.</sup>